# Example HTML layout changes over time

Tags: html, layout

What is the best way to get some example pages over time (any domain), specifically I'm interested in pages where the content is the same, while the DOM changed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried WayBack Machine?  http://archive.org/web/